# Quel verbe correspond à la « traçabilité » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes

Je cherche un verbe correspondant à l'action d'*effectuer une traçabilité* dans le cadre d'un site Web où l'on souhaite enregistrer les actions effectuées par les utilisateurs, par exemple l'utilisateur A a effectué un achat le JJ/MM/AAAA. J'ai pensé au verbe [tracer](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tracer) mais sa [définition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/tracer) ne semble pas correspondre et je ne trouve pas de [synonymes](http://www.crisco.unicaen.fr/des/synonymes/tracer) exprimant l'idée que je recherche.

Comment: Je proposerais aussi *traquer*. Mais plutot **creer** une trace, et non pas **suivre** une trace, qu'on cherche ici.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je pense que **tracer** est bien le verbe que vous cherchez :

> Suivre, par des technologies diverses, les déplacements de quelqu'un
>   ou de quelque chose : *Tracer des noctambules*, *un téléphone
>   portable*.
>
> [ *Dictionnaires français Larousse*, extrait de « [tracer](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/tracer/78848) » ]

Dans le monde professionnel, on **trace** les échanges avec le client par exemple, afin de pouvoir régler les litiges en cas de désaccord futur. Ceci permet de démontrer, grâce à la **trace [écrite]** que c'est bien ce qu'a demandé le client.

On va également parler de **tracer** les actions d'un utilisateur sur un site, c'est à dire **enregistrer en base de donnée** les pages vues ou **envoyer un mail confirmant la commande** par exemple.

Comment: Autant je pense que c'est la bonne réponse, autant j'ai du mal à trouver une attestation dans un dictionnaire en ligne (par exemple, le lien wiktionnaire que fournit A.L. ne mentionne rien dans ce sens, et un autre mentionne "suivre à la trace, poursuivre", mais rien qui parle d'enregistrer)

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Le problème est que "une trace" en dehors du monde professionnel est très utilisé pour décrire les traces d'animaux (dans la terre), ou des traces de peinture (sur les vêtements). Le terme "tracer" dans le sens souhaité est nouveau je pense. Nous l'utilisons quotidiennement dans mon entreprise de développement web.

Comment: J'ai trouvé une référence dans ce sens dans le Larousse, que j'ai rajouter dans ma réponse : **Suivre, par des technologies diverses, les déplacements de quelqu'un ou de quelque chose : Tracer des noctambules, un téléphone portable**

Comment: Admirable. Ce sens de *tracer* est nouveau : c'est aussi la conclusion à laquelle j'arrive, et ça me parait important à remarquer. (C'est pour ça que l'OP disait « ça ne semble par correspondre », notamment.)

Comment: J'ai l'impression que *tracer* est un emprunt à l'anglais venu du milieu informatique, j'évite les anglicismes en général mais celui-ci a une [origine française](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trace#Etymology_2) donc je l'accepte.

Answer (score 1):

Un complément au sujet de la « *traçabilité* » (emprunt à l'anglais, 1996, ISO : 2000; [par ex. avec ref. à diff. standards](https://books.google.com/books?id=kW7rBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA338&dq=Information%20technology%20%3A%20vocabulary.%20Part%2007.%20Computer%20programming&pg=PA317#v=onepage&q=trace&f=false)). On parle de la *capacité de pister*, de la possibilité d'identifier l'*origine* d'un produit, d'une donnée, etc. à n'importe quelle étape du traitement ou de l' « *[a]ptitude à retrouver l'historique, la mise en œuvre ou l'emplacement de ce qui est examiné.* » ([*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=TRACEABILITY), [aussi *GD*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26529852)). Il ne s'agit pas de quelque chose qu'on « effectue », mais plutôt de ce qu'on « assure », de ce que *permet* la mise en œuvre de différentes solutions; un objectif. Quant à [*tracer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tracer), on a dans la définition l'emploi de *tracer/[retracer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/retracer) l'historique (de qqc.)*; ça diffère de l'idée de *suivre à la trace/suivre la piste*, ou de celle de *suivre le déplacement* d'une commande qu'on utiliserait avec *tracer*.<sup>1</sup> En *informatique*, [*tracer*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8382273) et [*traçage*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8382285) dans le sens du *déroulement/dépistage/suivi à la trace*, avaient pris beaucoup de place avec le *programme* semble-t-il. En *comptabilité/gestion*, on des termes spécialisés avec faire un [*suivi des commandes*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17011247) ([2](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17037972)), des [*stocks en temps réel*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17035116), et l'[*audit*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1299105) d'éléments probants. Généralement, avec différents exemples de verbes, on a « *garder des [traces](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trace)* de » qui relève de l'impression psychique; « *[conserver](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conserver) la trace* », de l'empreinte d'un état antérieur sur un objet passif; et « *retrouver des traces* », le plus souvent avec matérialité, pour la marque qui témoigne de l'antériorité de qqc.. Mais le terme *traçabilité* vise une idée bien spécifique; qu'on sache que l' « *utilisateur A a effectué un achat le JJ/MM/AAAA* » correspond à mon avis bien concrètement à *connaître la date du placement/traitement d'une commande*.

---

Selon le contexte, il peut s'agir de *documenter* les transactions, de (conserver etc.) l'*historique* (complet/de certaines) *commandes* (du client), du placement à l'expédition/à la livraison; ou il peut s'agir littéralement de *traçabilité* et on veut permettre d' *identifier l'origine*, souvent d'un produit; dans d'autres cas on veut permettre/assurer techniquement un *suivi du déplacement* de quelque chose, *tracer*, ou on a aussi l'idée plus usuelle de moyens qui permettent éventuellement de *retrouver la trace de qqc.*, tel que nous l'apprend [la réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14010). On n'est pas à court de choix.

Le terme « *traçabilité* » correspond au *verbe* « *avoir la capacité d'avoir son origine identifiée/repérée/retrouvée* ».

---

<sub>1. J'ai noté qu'en anglais on voit à titre d'exemple que « [*to trace a call*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/fr/traduire/anglais-francais/trace) » c'est *trouver d'où vient un appel*; en identifier l'origine. Dans le contexte des *télécommunications* (géolocalisation) on retrouvait pour « [*tracing*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=frt&__index=frt&srchtxt=historique&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) » des trucs comme *repérage*, *dépistage*, et l'*historique*.</sub>